# Is it possible to get both Multipart file and a RequestBody in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipart

I want to have a post method in Springboot which will post data to database where I've a table which holds data of an employee and that includes resume as well. I want to have resume as a document hence I had byte[] on the entity class. I passed the document as Multipart/form-data from the postman and had the requestBody in the raw body section as JSON data. But couldn't do so.

I passed the document as Multipart/form-data from the postman and had the requestBody in the raw body section as JSON data with the controller written like,

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeMinimalResponseDTO> postEmployee(
            @RequestPart(value = "resume") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestBody(required = false) EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) throws IOException {
     Employee employee = Converters.getEmployeeFromEmployeeDto(employeeDTO);
     employee.setResume(file.getBytes());
     return this.employeeService.postEmployee(employee);
}
```

leads to an Internal Server Error saying 'Current request is not a multipart request'. What am I doing wrong ? Do I have to do any kind of configuration to make it work. I had [starter web, Data JPA, mysql Connector, Lombok] dependencies.

Here is my Application.properties,

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=7MB
```

followed by mysql configuration.

But, I had a controller to check the Multipart upload alone and that works fine like,

```
@PostMapping("check")
    public String fileUploadCheck(@RequestPart(value = "resume",required = false) MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
        Employee employee= new Employee();
        employee.setResume(file.getBytes());
        this.employeeService.postEmployee(employee);
        return "file uploaded successfullly..";
    }
```

which happily returns, "file uploaded successfullly.." I don't know why. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It seems everything is ok with your post service using @RequestPart annotation, maybe the problem is on the client side. Can you provide how are you sending the body and file to the service?

Comment: I currently don't have any front end page which access this api. I'm currently using the postman to hit the API. Since I was using the requestBody annotation to get the DTO object I've passed the JSON data in the raw body section and upload the file in the form-data section with content type multipart/form-data enabled. Still not getting it.

Comment: No you cannot have that. You either have the full body (`@RequestBody`) or parts of the body using `@RequestPart` combining them doesn't make sense. The `EmployeeDTO` would be a different part of the whole body and not the whole body. The body is basically all of the request and as this is a multipart it thuys has multiple parts.

Comment: @arunDarkDev An alternative option is to handle your file as part of the body request using base64 conversion. And then validate whatever you want (format, extension, content, etc...) in your service. Add a new parameter on `EmployeeDTO` of type String and use it to send your file as a base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @RequestPart, Here is an example.

```
save(@RequestPart(value = "file1", required = false) MultipartFile file1,
@RequestPart(value = "file2", required = false) MultipartFile file2,
@RequestPart MyDto myDto)
```

in your frontend

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file1', this.myForm.get('file1')?.value);
formData.append('MyDto', new Blob([JSON
      .stringify(MyModlel)], {
      type: 'application/json'
}));
```

Comment: Thanks man :) It worked when I used RequestPart and try to pass it from the form-data in the postman. So, we can't have RequestBody and RequestPart on the same API. is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC you can have both the file and an object (JSON) in one request body. But you should annotate the object as `@RequestParam` and not `@RequestBody`.

**Solution**

```java
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeMinimalResponseDTO> postEmployee(
            @RequestPart(value = "resume") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam(required = false) EmployeeDTO employeeDTO) throws IOException {
     Employee employee = Converters.getEmployeeFromEmployeeDto(employeeDTO);
     employee.setResume(file.getBytes());
     return this.employeeService.postEmployee(employee);
}
```

From `RequestParam` doc:

> In Spring MVC, "request parameters" map to query parameters, form
> data, and parts in multipart requests. This is because the Servlet API
> combines query parameters and form data into a single map called
> "parameters", and that includes automatic parsing of the request body.